# How to determine if given Azure DevOps PAT token is valid for all accessible organizations?

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, token, access-token

When creating a new personal access token on Azure DevOps, one can select its `Organization` to be `All accessible organizations`. How can I programmatically determine if a PAT token (a string) is valid for all accessible organizations, or only for one?

Most relevant Azure DevOps documentation I could find: [Authenticate access with personal access tokens for Azure DevOps Services and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=vsts).

Source which might be relevant: [Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/Microsoft.Alm.Authentication/Src/Token.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/blob/71f76428dc1efd48078809e89c7539fe4ae4d851/Microsoft.Alm.Authentication/Src/Token.cs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a request to

```
GET https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/profile/profiles/me?api-version=6.0
```

Only 'all accessible organization' PATs will get a valid response

You can then take the id of that response and call this to get more info on which organizations the PAT is an owner of / member of

```
GET https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/accounts?[ownerId|memberId]={idFromFirstReq}&api-version=6.0
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this url "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/profile/profiles/me?api-version=6.0" in my c# code, but I couldn't, It's always respond with 401
my PAT has full access, and my account is administrator!
I'm using the c# code that exists in this page: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts&tabs=Windows

Answer (score 2):

There's no API that I know of that validates a PAT or otherwise tells you information about it.

The easiest way to check if a PAT has access somewhere is to use it to access a REST API. If you get a 200, you're all good. If you get a 401, you don't have access. Listing projects is a pretty safe operation that basically any PAT that has access to an organization is going to be able to do:

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects/?api-version=4.1`

Comment: there was this response which seemed to get information about the owner of the PAT: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53190769/validate-the-azure-devops-pat